# Using manufacturer SSD tools under MSWin on SSDs used under Unix (Linux/OS X)?

Tags: ssd, maintenance

The manufacturers of the SSDs I currently use all have their own tools for lowlevel maintenance, which usually also work only on internal drives (i.e. no USB-attached externals). Too bad apparently for people using other platforms but it's easy enough nowadays to make a bootable MSWin install using WinToUSB for this kind of periodic maintenance/rescue.
To date I've used such a tool once (Verbatim's) to do an "optimisation" (must have been a TRIM) but which took much longer than expected on a drive that had been repartitioned not long ago and only used for some performance testing. EDIT: IOW, this suggests something more thorough was being done.

On Linux, TRIM seems to be something that's linked to the filesystem (EDIT: yes, I know how to do a TRIM under Linux!) so I have to wonder if those MSWin manufacturer tools are safe for use on drives containing non-Microsoft filesystems?

EDIT: Verbatim's tool: https://filecr.com/windows/verbatim-ssd-utility/?id=901417034000 (I haven't found a dedicated page on their site)

Kingston's manager: https://www.kingston.com/en/support/technical/ssdmanager

WD's dashboard: https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/31759/kw/Western%20Digital%20Dashboard

Comment: Are you really asking how to perform a trim on an SSD from a Linux-based system?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here, and how it relates to Linux/UNIX. Start with defining "those tools": There's very many vendors of SSDs, and there's even more tools, and it's not clear what the tools you refer to even do…

Comment: (and when it comes to my opinion on whether gratis vendor "add-on and maintenance tools" for commodity hardware are safe: you're probably safer without them, even in a micrcosoft-only environment. If you can't explain what a tool really does, you probably don't need it.)

Comment: While you're here, RJVB, please would you review your other questions and look at whether you can accept ✔ any suitable answers. 1 of 7 seems a little low. Thanks

Comment: "_On Linux, TRIM seems to be something that's linked to the filesystem (yes, I know how to do a TRIM under Linux!)_" - this suggests you _do not_ know about trim

Comment: at least the verbatim tool looks like an intern's job that offers nothing that board utilities under Linux and OS X wouldn't offer either, so not quite sure what you're then asking us? the question of whether it is safe to operate a TRIM utility on a filesystem it doesn't understand answers itself by answering the question of what it *does* in that case, which we can't know.

Comment: "board utilities"?

Comment: @roaima - I said how to do a trim under Linux without claiming it's exhaustive knowledge (fstrim & `zpool trim`). I never made any claims about knowing what trim does/is; that knowledge is vague at best. Idem for what happens when you unlink/remove a file